# Should the default edit summaries be in sentence case?

Tags: feature-request, bug, edits, edit-summary, capitalization

I'm not entirely *au fait* with the site's inner workings so I'm not sure if this is a [bug](/questions/tagged/bug), [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) or if it's actually [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign), hence the open question.<sup>1</sup>

The default edit summaries are not capitalised. Here, for example:

[image]

I've not screenshot all the other default summaries that I am aware of, but none (apart from the final one, below) are similarly not capitalised:

- added *n* characters in body
- deleted *n* characters in body
- edited body
- edited title
- rolled back to previous question

Oddly though, this one is in title case:

- **R**ollback to **R**evision *n*

Athough edit summaries are not expressly referred to in the "Use sentence casing" section of the [style guide](https://stackoverflow.design/content/guidelines/grammar-and-mechanics/#use-sentence-casing), by my reading of it they should be capitalised for consistency across the network.

Or have I missed something?

---

<sup>1</sup>I've not been able to locate a duplicate specifically on this topic, but do note the final bullet point of this apparently unresolved [feature request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/199971/906208) from just under 10 years' ago that refers to using sentence case in the edit-comment field.

Comment: When you want something changed and not sure if bug or feature request, just have both and let the developer who will handle this remove one. :)

Comment: Related: The default image text (*"enter image description here"*)

Comment: Yes, it probably should. There's a lot of outdated parts of the interface that adhered to the former practice of just displaying everything in lowercase, before the company implemented the [Stacks design principles](https://stackoverflow.design), which [recommend sentence casing](https://stackoverflow.design/content/guidelines/grammar-and-mechanics/#use-sentence-casing). In this case, it's not a heading or a call-to-action, but I don't think there's a reason not to use sentence casing here as well.